# Website takes a long time to load due to steam's inventory api request, how do I fix this?

Tags: php, api, steam

I have a small issue, I'm currently trying to display a user's inventory using steam's API, everything that I wanted is done. (it gets the players items, name and displays the skin's image) however it takes a good 9-30seconds for the webpage to load, is it possible to make the loading of the data faster?

```
                              <?php 
                    if(!isset($_SESSION["steamid"])): ?>
                    <a> Log In so you can see your inventory! </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="GetInventory">

                         <?php  
                        $player = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/" . $_SESSION["steamid"] . "/inventory/json/730/2");
                        $player = json_decode($player, true);
                        foreach($player["rgDescriptions"] as $item) {
                               $result = @file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=" . str_replace(" ", "%20", $item["market_hash_name"]));
                               $result = json_decode($result, true);
                       if(!empty($result["success"]) && $result["success"] == true && !empty($result["median_price"]))
                                echo '<img id= "skinimg" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/' . $item["icon_url"] . '"> ' . $item["name"] . " - " . $result["median_price"] . "<br>";}
                        ?>

                    <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code I currently have,does anyone have any sugestion?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiHQL.png

Comment: Cache the data so you don't have to do the requests all the time. You could/should also make it asyncronous, ie load the page without the user data, then load the user data afterwards using js/ajax. It will still take a while to load the data if it isn't cached but at least the site will load.

Comment: you can do this all client side via JS, that way your server isn't involved in the request at all.

Comment: @JimL I think caching the data wouldn't be a viable option, an easier alternative could be having the div load after the page is loaded, the user doesn't need to have imidiate access to the inventory, so i guess it can load in the background while the page is shown.